# Can I have have 2 polymer elements in one HTML

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have created two Dart app using Polymer. The two tags created are: `weather-tag` and `qotd-tag`.

In `weather-tag`, I am getting weather information from a remote service and in `qotd-tag` I am getting qotd from local machine. Both running fine in Dart and also in compiled JS.

I am now integrating these two Dart "widget" into my own `index.html`.

The HTML snippet is like following:

```html
<html lang="zh-CN">
    <head>
        <script src="/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="/packages/custom_element/custom-elements.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="/packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="/getqotd.html_bootstrap.dart.js"></script>
        <script src="/getweather.html_bootstrap.dart.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body id="home">
    <polymer-element name="qotd-tag">
        <template>...
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
    <polymer-element name="weather-tag">
        <template>...
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
                        <weather-tag></weather-tag>
                        <qotd-tag></qotd-tag>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is it only shows the `qotd-tag`.

If I took out all `qotd-tag` related reference (js, polymer-element, the tag), `weather-tag` can be displayed correctly.

If I change the sequence of the two js file (weather.js comes first and then qotd.js), now it shows only the weather-tag.

I think there must be some conflict in the js declaration.

I can solve this issue by building a new tag with the two tags' functions but **is there a way to have two or more polymer-element** in one HTML file?

Comment: The code you provided has IMHO nothing to do with Dart. It seems you have built something to JavaScript and are trying to build an app from the generated parts. Dart development doesn't work like that. You develop entirely in Dart (even Polymer elements) and build the entire result to JavaScript at once.

Comment: This is something I'd love to see in Dart development. 

The theme might (and should) be like this: various Dart developers develops Dart apps and for normal HTML programmers, these Dart apps can be imported like a widget seamlessly.

My HTML snippets shown above is pure frontend but trying to incorporate "existing" Dart apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can import and use two elements in a Dart app:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="import" href="foo_element.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bar_element.html">

    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <foo-element></foo-element>
    <bar-element></bar-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

For the full code, look at this gist:

https://gist.github.com/shailen/8055849

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean, but yes, this uses Dart code.

Comment: Hi Tuli, 

I don't want to "integrate" the two Dart widgets in another Dart app and I know how to do that. 

I want to integrate the two Dart widgets in my frontend HTML. This situation applies like this:

1. Imagine there are a lot of Dart widgtes (a Dart widget lib) with many pre-compiled JS version of Dart app;
2. People can grab from there and use whatever they want by just inserting a JS, links to the Dart widget, put in the template and done!

Now it is impossible.

Comment: You are correct. As of now, the free intermingling of Dart and JS widgets isn't possible in the way that you describe.